# AngularJS Data Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, architecture

I've created a model service with AngularJS that acts as a hub for all data being stored. It contains several arrays and (hash) maps that store specific data objects. One such data object for example is called Game. Obviously objects of type Game should not be Singleton since there can be multiple of these. My questions is: Does AngularJS provide any patterns similar to Service/Factory that objects like Game should follow to be well-integrated into the AngularJS paradigm?

Comment: Have an array of `Game` objects in the service.

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides factories, services, and providers. They are all singletons.  Since Game is not a singleton, it is not suitable as an angular factory, service, or provider. However, there is nothing stopping you from providing methods on the singleton for creating new games, registering games, and returning games as a list, etc:

```
GameService  (singleton) 

GameService.CreateNewGame() // registers a new game

GameService.GetAllGames() // returns all games

GameService.RemoveGame(game) // removes a game
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! I wondered whether there was a specific recipe for data objects like these in AngularJS (similar to Service/Factory/Provider).